# For a Swagger API page, how do you get the correct OAuth2 bearer token for Azure Active Directory (AAD)?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, oauth-2.0, swagger

I have a Swagger API page that works as expected when I copy and paste a correct bearer token (from the UI) into Swagger.

I am able to do that via the Bearer (apiKey) Authorize Form (see code below).

Now I would like Swagger to use OAuth2 and AAD in order to generate the bearer token itself (so I do not have to copy/paste the token).

This should be possible via the OAuth2 Authorize Form (see code below), however it is adding an incorrect bearer token...

I am not sure if it's a code issue, or a configuration issue within Azure?

I do have OAuth2 configured correct (enough) so that it asks you to login via Azure, and within Azure I have configured a redirect url there so that it can come back to my swagger page with a token, however it comes back with an invalid token.

By decoding the token I can see that no matter what I do, either the iss claim and/or the aud claim are incorrect (or at least different from what is coming over from the UI's token)

I also noticed that by changing the scope that I pass in I can change the claims there, however I can never get the correct value in the aud claim (closest I've gotten is that value into the azp claim).

Is there something I can change in the code, or in Azure in order to get the correct aud claim??

What are the exact steps to get the correct scope for an api??
by changing the scope to api:///user_impersonation I seem to be able to change those claims, but still cannot get the correct values and a valid token.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(o =>
            {
                o.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });

                // Bearer (apiKey) Authorize Form
                o.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Name = "authorization",
                    Scheme = "bearer"
                });
                // OAuth2 Authorize Form  (TODO: wrong token?)
                o.AddSecurityDefinition("OAuth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                    {
                        Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                        {
                            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
                            TokenUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
                            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string> 
                            {
                                { "User.Read", "API" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                o.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        // Bearer (apiKey) Header
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Bearer",
                            },
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header
                        },
                        new List<string>()
                    },
                    {
                        // OAuth2 Header
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme 
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference 
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "OAuth2"
                            },
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header
                        },
                        new List <string> ()
                    }
                });
            });
```

....

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(o =>
            {
                o.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API V1");
                o.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;

                o.OAuthClientId("<client id>");
            });
```

[image]

I found 2 authentication apps and have tried everything I can think of on both.
[image]
[image]

And finally, here is the authentication code that we're using for the api in case there is some mismatch there somehow?

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://sts.windows.net/<tenant id>/v2.0";
                options.Audience = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").GetSection("Audience").Value;
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;
            });
```

Comment: Have you seen my article on this? https://joonasw.net/view/testing-azure-ad-protected-apis-part-1-swagger-ui

Comment: Hello @juunas thank you for reaching out, I actually did pull down your solution to look around the other day. I will try to set it back up and let you know what happens.

Comment: we only have the 1 Authorize tag and I feel like I've done everything token related the same as you have it now, but unfortunately still getting a bad token somehow..

Comment: @juunas any thoughts on how the token could be wrong?  do you think it's an issue with my scopes?  or maybe something else?

Comment: @juunas reading the comments from your blog I found that the aud claim is not set correctly, and the iss claim is surprising set to https://sts.windows.net on the incorrect one instead of the expected https://login.microsoftonline.com..  any idea on how to correct those 2 claims from Swagger?  Or is it something in my Azure config?

Comment: Yeah you are getting a "v1" token but your back-end is expecting a v2 token. You can set `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2` in the app registration's Manifest to get v2 tokens. Or you can change your config to accept v1 tokens.

Comment: @juunas i feel like i'm so close.  but it's still getting an incorrect aud claim.  i feel like i might be using an incorrect scope, changing that I can get the correct iss claim, but no luck on the aud still.  i tried change the value to 2 also still no luck :(

Comment: also i am now "able" to get this error too if this means anything: System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden. For more det

Comment: the value that should be in the aud claim is present in the azp claim...

Comment: The scope you use defines the aud value. This should usually be a scope defined on your API app registration. And since your API is configured with the API app registration's values, it would then accept the token.

Comment: @juunas Do I need to create a Scope and/or Authorized client applications on the "Expose an API" tab?  or what should the scope be, should it start with api://?

Comment: You need a scope on the Expose an API tab.